# Has artificial selection / selective breeding ever been targeted at intelligence?

Tags: evolution, dogs, selection, artificial-selection

Has it ever been attempted to breed a species, for example dogs, to maximize some aspect of intelligence? I find it particularly interesting to imagine one could selectively breed dogs to be able to talk or develop far more advanced communication structures.

Is there anything we know that could help us predict how many generations of breeding this might take?

Has this idea even been abstracted or generalized to a general technique of “targeted breeding”, where, in a highly methodical and systematic, scientific way, someone pinpoints some specific, even measurable trait, and then with as much automation as possible, tries to artificially breed many generations of an organism to continually maximize that trait, as fast as possible?

Comment: when you researced this what did you find?

Comment: I'll briefly note that when applied to a human context (which is the most common for this question), this kind of breeding is called "eugenics" and usually frowned upon. Assuming that you are interested in breeding dogs, I'll point you in the direction of the [breeder's equation](https://www.nature.com/scitable/knowledge/library/the-breeder-s-equation-24204828/). But I'll also point you to the [wiki page on IQ heritability (in humans)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heritability_of_IQ), which has a number of important caveats. IDK if they apply equally to dogs.

Comment: Hi! Many dogs have been bred to be more alert and bark a lot rather than be bulkier and more aggressive, precisely using a systematic breeding method, maybe not as precise as scientific research. Would that count? This question is hard to answer without a common reference framework for intelligence.

Comment: @MaximilianPress - It must pertain to dogs as well. I bred Border Collies, and while I didn't employ a scientific method, some were more "intelligent" than others, and one of them was absolutely outstanding, demonstrating easy familiarity with syntax and *concepts*.

Comment: your last paragraph more or less exactly describes the process of artificial selection, which is being done all the time in agricultural - selecting animals or plants for increased crop yields, etc etc.

Answer (score 5):

> Has it ever been attempted to breed a species, for example dogs, to maximize some aspect of intelligence?

Yes, perhaps unintentionally, but certainly to serve a purpose: to better herd sheep.

Border Collies (BC) are widely considered to be among the most intelligent of dog breeds. For (at least) hundreds of years, they have been selectively bred to herd sheep, playing on a dog's natural prey drive.

By listening for and obeying different whistles/[verbal commands](https://elkana.info/border-collie-activities/herding-terminology-for-working-sheep-dog-uk.html) for different actions, a working BC at minimum learns whether or not to approach the flock, find the sheep, gather them into a group, move them towards the shepherd or not, towards the right, towards the left, leave the flock to go back for strays, speed up, slow down, walk, stop, lie down, bark, and come back (you're done.) There are also other commands, but those few are *the minimum*. (I've seen a BC cut 3 sheep *by name* out of a flock of ?50-60 sheep and herd them into a separate enclosure. They were not marked.)

By selecting, for generations, the most responsive dogs to breed, BCs have become finely attuned to look to humans for commands of all kinds, and to obey them.

While they may not ever learn to talk (not only vocal cords, but the entire mouth including most of the tongue is needed for speech), they can still communicate. A BC named [Chaser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaser_(dog)) was trained to learn the names of over a thousand toys, many of them being similar (e.g. red ball, fuzzy ball, big elephant, little elephant, white elephant, etc.). The trainer, a psychologist, stopped at 1022 objects because of space and he was kind of bored at that point. The dog could find a photograph of the object by name, and could find on the first try without help an unknown toy in a group of familiar toys when the owner made up a new name, understanding the concept of *unfamiliar*. He taught her verbs, adverbs, adjectives, and syntax. She could follow a string of commands successfully.

Word buttons are now being used to study canine cognition, the most well known example of these dogs being [Bunny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunny_(dog)) the Sheepadoodle. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z8k2upr9vCE) video explains Bunny's progress and ability to communicate using abstract ideas, like "ouch" and "stranger", and emotions. This is as close to talking as we are likely to get with dogs.

<sub>Sadly, Bunny often indicated that she was sad, very sad ("Big Sad") and worried ("Concerned") and **has asked for medications for relief**. Scout's honor. (How 'human' is *that*?) Personally, I can't understand someone doubting the capacity for intelligence (and emotions) in dogs after seeing these dogs in action.</sub>

<sub>If you can stand another anecdote, read on. Border Collies are ["soft dogs"](https://dogtraining.world/knowledge-base/hard-soft-dogs/), meaning they don't like hard corrections, e.g. they react negatively at being yelled at. My grandfather, a farmer who had a small herd of dairy cows, could tell his Border Collie which cows he wanted her to round up and bring in at milking time, and she would do so. In the summer, cows are milked twice a day. One summer evening she missed a cow, which is kind of a big deal, as missing even one milking can decrease milk production for days. Uncharacteristically annoyed, my grandfather angrily yelled at her to go back out and get said cow, which she did. She then disappeared for 24 hours, making my grandfather go fetch his own damned cows from the fields. Did she disappear because her feelings were hurt, or to teach him a lesson? I don't know, but my grandfather never yelled at her again.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

The [Wikipedia article on "Selective breeding"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selective_breeding), which I went to while composing a comment on your question, has this sentence:

> A Soviet attempt to breed lab rats with higher intelligence led to cases of neurosis severe enough to make the animals incapable of any problem solving unless drugs like phenazepam were used.[14]

The reference given is in Russian (see [here](https://archive.ph/20140809185752/http://www.znanie-sila.ru/golden/issue2print_9.html)), but even with Google Translate it's hard to get much out of it.

A [Google search on "'artificial selection' learning evolution"](https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?q=%22artificial+selection%22+learning+evolution) brings up a lot, but nothing that I can find specifically on selection for intelligence: there are experiments on artificial selection for brain size in guppies, reversal learning (cognitive flexibility) in birds (*Parus major*), learning rates in parasitic wasps ...